# How to access specific values in JSON by keys using $.each()

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to access specific values from a JSON file by the key `lat` as I loop through each record. However I have been getting `undefined` result as I printed them.

**JSON**

```
[{"pid":4317129482,"lat":"51.5078","lon":"-0.10467","coords":{"x":-0.10467,"y":51.5078},"points":{"x":-0.10467,"y":51.5078}},
{"pid":4356791546,"lat":"51.522","lon":"-0.101773","coords":{"x":-0.101773,"y":51.522},"points":{"x":-0.101773,"y":51.522}},
```

The JSON is stored in `data`

**Code attempted**

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){  
                            if (key == "lat") {
                                console.log(value)
                            }
```

OR

```
$.each(data, function(item){    
                            console.log(item.lat)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
   console.log(value.lat); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON you have posted is proper, its an array of objects. So `$.each(data,function(key,val){})` would return index and the object i.e. key would be 0,1,2 and value the object.

To access

> "lat":"51.522"

you have to do

```
$.each(data,function(key,val){
    //val here is your object. For each object in the array you have to loop again 
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
        //now since val is an object looping through it will return your key-value pairs
        if(k == 'lat'){
        //Do something
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps change the argument names to be more of an indication of what you are looping over with `$.each`

For array something like:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, arrayElement){

})
```

For object

```
$.each(obj, function(objKey, propertyValue){

});
```

When uncertain what's inside the loop use `console.log([index, arrayElement])` so you can inspect it in browser  dev tools console